# Order by Date this list

Tags: php, wordpress, code-snippets, wordpress-shortcode

i have created this Php code to show a list by category.

Actually the list shows by  alphabetical order.

I would like to show by create date.

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms( 'category' );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<div class="product-category-list">';
    $x = 1;
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<div class='product-category-item bg-class-{$x}'>";
        $icon = pods_field( 'category', $term->term_id, 'immagine_categoria', true );
        $icon_url = $icon['guid'];
        $icon_thumb = pods_image_url ( $icon_url, 'large', 0, false ) ;
        $term_link = get_term_link($term);
     
        echo '<div class="product-category-image">';
        echo '<img src="'.$icon_thumb.'" alt="">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-category-title">';
        echo '<h3>'.$term->name.'</h3>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-category-description">'.$term->description.'</div>'; 
        echo '<div class="product-category-link">';
        echo '<a class="product-category-button" href="'.$term_link.'">Visualizza Categoria</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        $x++;

        if ($x > 3) {
            $x = 1;
        }

    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Terms don't store creation date, unless you save it as a term meta

Answer (score 0):

There is no `orderby` `date` in `get_terms()`. check below comments.

```
 *     @type string       $orderby                Field(s) to order terms by. Accepts:
 *                                                - term fields ('name', 'slug', 'term_group', 'term_id', 'id',
 *                                                  'description', 'parent', 'term_order'). Unless `$object_ids`
 *                                                  is not empty, 'term_order' is treated the same as 'term_id'.
 *                                                - 'count' to use the number of objects associated with the term.
 *                                                - 'include' to match the 'order' of the $include param.
 *                                                - 'slug__in' to match the 'order' of the $slug param.
 *                                                - 'meta_value', 'meta_value_num'.
 *                                                - the value of `$meta_key`.
 *                                                - the array keys of `$meta_query`.
 *                                                - 'none' to omit the ORDER BY clause.
 *                                                Defaults to 'name'.
 *     @type string       $order                  Whether to order terms in ascending or descending order.
 *                                                Accepts 'ASC' (ascending) or 'DESC' (descending).
```

So you can pass `'orderby => 'ID',`  and `'order' => 'DESC'` so this will give you category by created order. check below code.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    'orderby'  => 'id', 
    'order'    => 'DESC'
); 
$terms = get_terms( $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    echo '<div class="product-category-list">';
    $x = 1;
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        echo "<div class='product-category-item bg-class-{$x}'>";
        $icon = pods_field( 'category', $term->term_id, 'immagine_categoria', true );
        $icon_url = $icon['guid'];
        $icon_thumb = pods_image_url ( $icon_url, 'large', 0, false ) ;
        $term_link = get_term_link($term);
     
        echo '<div class="product-category-image">';
        echo '<img src="'.$icon_thumb.'" alt="">';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-category-title">';
        echo '<h3>'.$term->name.'</h3>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div class="product-category-description">'.$term->description.'</div>'; 
        echo '<div class="product-category-link">';
        echo '<a class="product-category-button" href="'.$term_link.'">Visualizza Categoria</a>';
        echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';

        $x++;

        if ($x > 3) {
            $x = 1;
        }

    }
    echo '</div>';

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lets try to sort the array first then display it. These are the some function that uses to sort the array.

```
asort() //sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the value
ksort() //sort associative arrays in ascending order, according to the key
arsort() //sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the value
krsort() //sort associative arrays in descending order, according to the key
```

Also check this article.
https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/php/php+array+sort+by+column

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question?  This is just a list of sorting functions.

Comment: I am trying to say sort your array first with respect to date and then display them through loop.

Comment: Ok. So show how you would do that rather than state functions. Then you'll have a useful answer.